# Chrone Job Ranking in C# and SQL Server - light-weight application scheduler

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ranking

I have users on my website who play questions. The one who will give the most number of correct answers gets a reward the next day. If multiple people have given the same number of the correct answer, then the time taken is the tie-breaker.

I store `# of correct answers` and `time taken in seconds` in my SQL Server table  `Results`. The maximum time allowed for any question paper is 200 seconds. I also have a `rank` column in this table.

On the scenario above I require your help on below:

1. Any logic with the help of which I can get a weighted score that can help me show ranking the next day.
2. How to run a code that will rank the records of last days' results and can automatically show the top performers, in the descending order of scores
3. I don't want to use quarts or threading (time tick) based answers as I am using shared hosting.
4. I am thinking aloud maybe I am wrong, however: is there any EXTERNAL service from Google, Yahoo or any other on the web which can call a web service of my website and I can do the aforementioned task in that we service (this is inhouse web service)
5. If point 4 is feasible then, how can I rank the data of previous days' players and again save them after putting RANK?

I am using ASP.NET, C#, .NET Framework v4.5 and SQL Server 2014.

Comment: sounds like a simple update query will do the job

Comment: This is true that ultimately I need to run an update query however this will be fired automatically for all users one by one or in batch. Please note that this will be run on the next day not when the user is doing activity on the website. @Squirrel